# Bootstrap IE7 modal close button alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

The Bootstrap 2 modal has a close button, but it's not placed correctly in IE7. Since this is a fairly popular CSS library, I'm wondering if anyone has a good solution for IE7 to align it properly. It's a problem with the float, but I'm not sure how to fix this rendering issue.

[image: close button]

Comment: IE7? Are you still using that?

Comment: We still have clients that use IE6 and IE7.  Ridiculous as it seems, we either support our clients and get paid to do so, or turn business away on a technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just put a modal together in ie7 and looked ok... Have you added any CSS?

Can you put your code into a fiddle or something?

cheers

```
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>       

  </body>
```

Comment: Please not this is with regards to IE7 and Bootstrap 2. For the question, it's the sample code on the bootstrap website which has this issue. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

If you give the h3 a display:inline property it should line up properly.